# python not working in cmd until path given

Tags: python, cmd

I had to format my laptop and python was installed, but there is something different now, before formatting when I open CMD and type python it runs without anything else, but now I have to change the directory to run python (`cd C:\Users\Khaled\Desktop\python`) to run, what can I do to run python without changing directory??

Comment: You probably need to add the directory that contains your Python executable to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: if you are on windows termianl (https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-add-python-to-path-variable-in-windows)  if you are using gitbash for windows you can make an alias to python in your .bashrc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install python in C: drive then set Environment Variable
by Right click on My COMPUTER icon then select properties
then got Advance system Setting if Window PC
then select Environment Variable and give path of your Python where you installed
for example if in C Drive
C:\python39\Scripts;C:\python39
python39 is my folder name of python installed directory which is in C drive

set user and sysem variable by click on edit option